# Query to list all tables that contain a specific column with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Question as stated in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,c.name AS column_name
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
        ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%'
ORDER BY 
    schema_name
    ,table_name;
```